# Determine if my terminal can use an ANSI escape code in python

Tags: python, ansi-escape

I'm using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to add colour and other effects (like bold) to the output of my python program.

Using something like:

```
 print "\033[1mThis should be in bold"
```

Will print the "This should be in bold" in my terminal.

However:

```
print "\033[3mThis should be in italics"
```

Does not print the text in terminal, I assume my terminal does not support it.

Is there any way to determine which codes are supported by the terminal? The link above states that italics is "Not widely supported. Sometimes treated as inverse."

Is there a way (in python) to:

1. Test if a machine supports an ANSI code.
2. Test if a machine supports a code but uses an alternative output (i.e. I might try to use italics but the terminal actually prints in inverse)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159718/programmatically-detect-the-ansi-escape-code-supported-by-terminal

Answer (score 0):

The [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) library was designed for almost exactly this purpose.  Back in the day when everything was terminal-based, there was a need for a portable way to do things like display bold text, or to clear the screen.  `terminfo` works by comparing the value of your `TERM` environment variable to a database of terminal capabilities.

It looks as Python's `curses` module provides an interface to these libraries.

There is an example [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/475116-using-terminfo-for-portable-color-output-cursor-co/) that looks like it does what you want.