# How to check if sys.stderr supports colors?

Tags: python, stdout, stderr

Say, if we want to output to the console in color, I'd do:

```
import sys

red = '\033[31m'
restore = '\033[0m'

sys.stderr.write(f"{red}Error message{restore}")
```

But how to tell if `sys.stderr` supports colors?

I need this to know if it doesn't, and in that case avoid printing `\033[` parts.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904152/determine-if-my-terminal-can-use-an-ansi-escape-code-in-python

Comment: @AndrejKesely is there any guarantee that stderr goes to the same place as stdout?

Comment: I don't think you can change the colors for sys.stderr.

Comment: As Andrej points out in their comment the only mechanism is to interrogate the `TERM` env var terminfo definition. There is no way to ask the terminal if it supports colors.